# How to open new browser window using icefaces?

Tags: javascript, jsf

How to open new browser window using icefaces

```
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "window.open('printerFriendly.html','Print','width=300','height=200','menubar=yes','status=yes','location=yes','toolbar=yes','scrollbars=yes')");
```

but not able to open the page, please help me

Comment: jsf with icefaces , so i cann't use html.

Comment: Again, why? You can mix html and jsf...

Comment: Consider **registering** your user account. Now you've a lot of questions with unaccepted answers spread out over different accounts. http://stackoverflow.com/users/293339, http://stackoverflow.com/users/388720, http://stackoverflow.com/users/388945, http://stackoverflow.com/users/392116, http://stackoverflow.com/users/418228, http://stackoverflow.com/users/383890, http://stackoverflow.com/users/437700, http://stackoverflow.com/users/436514, http://stackoverflow.com/users/415565 and http://stackoverflow.com/users/412351

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use plain vanilla html?

```
<a href="printerFriendly.html" target="_blank">Print</a>
```